# How can I make a simple volumetric light on Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light, volumetrics

I'm trying to do a volumetric light on Cycles, and I've followed tutorials, but nothing has worked yet. How can I make a proper volumetric light in Blender, like the following one?

[image: Example light]

But to leave the light in the middle, like, almost a star, is this possible? I'm at the point to use an image plane besides the light which would be better... **I need to use it moving the camera.**

I'm actually trying to do this because I want to simulate the brightness of the Sun.

I tried the effect, but it still gave me an error:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That kind of effect is easier to do in the compositor using a **Glare** node. Is not as computationally intensive as dealing with volumetrics.

[image]

[image]

If you absolutely want to do it with volumetrics you can try this:

Around a sphere that works as the emitter, place an object that will give you the shape of the rays.

[image]

Give it an opaque material and make it invisible to the camera.

[image]

[image]

Add scattering and absorption to your world's **volume** settings.

[image]

[image]

Keep in mind that when dealing with volume scattering and volume absorption your lights might need to be much, much brighter, and you'll be dealing with increased noise and possibly more fireflies. So you'll need a lot more samples and maybe and play with the settings for clamp indirect.

Comment: I updated my question's description, the problem is still happening, can you please see it? :/

Comment: @beavoru the volume absorption/scatter goes to to the **volume** input not to the surface of the world settings

Comment: Allright, let me try!

Answer (score 1):

For reasons of simplification you could use the compositor. There are several filters for this case (Blur, Fog Glare, Streaks, and more).

If you are not planning to move your camera, you could also use the [Sunbeam filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU2Lq.png).

Comment: Thanks, but actually i need to move the camera, ill add that to the description :/