# Why there is no light coming inside from the window

Tags: light

I have made the model with Archimesh addon. I want light should produce voulmetric type from the window inside the room. I have used spot as light source and strength as 100 default. But there is no light coming inside the light. What setting im missing so that light should transparent the glass windows.[image]

Comment: Please read [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles). You will need to change the material accordingly for better results. In the future, please provide images of materials when you have material questions.

Comment: It sounds like you are following the new tutorial from Andrew Price. Perhaps you should watch it a bit more carefully. http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/interior-architecture/

Comment: @Timaroberts, Ezra and cegaton, Just want to ask If i add a normal glass material y there is no light inside. Why there is so many plugin and plugout for complex material is ok just for a glass material let light come inside.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the glass issue pointed out by @Timaroberts your model has lots of problems The most important one is that **Materials created in blender internal will not work on cycles**, you need to create new materials using cycles shaders.

Then: Unconnected nodes have no effect.

[image]

Never connect nodes on a redundant loop (see the red line?)

[image]

Then you have a big box with a solidify modifier surrounding all of the "room", so that even if your materials were correctly set, that box would not let light through the glass anyway...

[image]

Fix all of that before you can have volumetrics... to set it up read this post:

[Atmospheric lighting in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45153/atmospheric-lighting-in-cycles/45154#45154)

Comment: @Timaroberts, Ezra and cegaton, Just want to ask If i add a normal glass material y there is no light inside. Why there is so many plugin and plugout for complex material is ok just for a glass material let light come inside.

Comment: The glass shader alone will not work. It will not light through without the transparent shader and the light path. Please read the link provided by @Timaroberts: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles .