# Why I can't see Godrays and How to Improve my overall scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I'm making a scene for commercial curtains and I thought of using Godrays but for some reason it doesn't show up as I want and also I feel like something is lacking from my Scene

I'll attach the basic file for Godrays settings

[image]

[image: First Shot]

[image: Second Shot]

Comment: The scene seems to me too bright to generate such effect (also in reality). Godrays are result of light ray hitting particles (dust, humidity) in a dark envi. So probably consider to use some post-pro technique.

Comment: @vklidu thanks man, Almost forgot how it worked irl, I'll surely render it in dark env and then compose it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Compositor – Sun Beams

Similar effect can be faked by compositor. Here I used alpha (when rendered without background)...

[image]

... as the source for Sun Beams node

[image]

[image]

[image]

A bit difficult for complex scene with a lot of objects in between beams ... but could be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

*The scene seems to me too bright to generate such effect (also in reality). Godrays are result of light ray hitting particles (dust, humidity) in a dark envi make the light visible, that is hard in such a shiny room.*

### Volume Scatter

In this example I increased Sun Strength to 100, Volume Scatter to 0.1 and all materials are set completely black (disconnected *Output* nodes) to get this result.

What helps to make it sharper is under *Render Properties > Light Paths > Max Bounces >* **Volume set to zero**.

[image]

So probably consider to use some post-pro technique.
Like render scene without volumetric object ...

[image]

... and Volume separately ...

[image]

... and mix it, but still (even contrasted) it doesn't seem to look natural too much.

[image]

---

**Side Notes:**
*Render Properties > Light Paths > Max Bounces > Volume* set with higher value doesn't mean sharper, because bouncing light ray is more spreader across a scene. That is correct in reality, but you want to avoid that. Here is volume object covering whole room to see effect better.

[image]

What I expected that should make it sharper is change
*Render Properties > Volumes >* **Step Rate** to something lower like 0.01, but when I tried it. for Viewport there wasn't difference, hm.

Comment: A question tho, why did you changed volume bounce to 0, I thought the higher the number the clearer it is and setting to 0 would mean it'd completely avoid it, And Thanks a lot for the info on Scatter and sun settings.

Comment: See edit ... notes

Answer (score 1):

In order to use godrays, place a cube around your whole scene. Make the cube have a volume scatter node in its material slot, and change the density to around .1. If you have a directional light in your scene (spotlight, area light, etc.) You will be able to see godrays. More info here: [How to do volumetric lighting for a forest scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109746/how-to-do-volumetric-lighting-for-a-forest-scene)

(They said in the link to change the world's volume, but that won't work if you have an HDRi)