# Create a light material which is seen as a focus in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, volumetrics

How can I make a light material which is seen as a focus?

[image]

Comment: please specify which render engine you need: internal or cycles? btw that is called a "spot light" with "halo/mist effect"

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16594/how-can-a-light-cone-volumetric-be-setup-with-cycles

Comment: What do you mean by "seen as focus"?

Comment: Exact same question, with the same reference image: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24493/is-it-possible-to-make-visible-spotlight-lightraysimage   other related links: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38830/volumetric-spot-light-with-cycles and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45153/atmospheric-lighting-in-cycles/45154#45154 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31599/how-can-i-make-a-simple-volumetric-light-on-cycles

Answer (score 3):

To achieve that kind of look in Cycles, you need to use *Volumetrics*. The light can be normal spotlight. To make scene have volumetrics, you have two options:

1. Make a cube (or any other shape) that encloses the scene. Add a new material to this object. In *Material* tab, for Surface select *Disconnect* and for Volume select *Volume Scatter*, and adjust the density to suit your scene (usually needs to be much less than the default 1, try between 0.3 and 0.01)
2. In *World* tab, for Volume, select *Volume Scatter* with same settings than above. You don't have to disconnect the world surface.

To get the result in pic you linked, you only need to do one of the two.