# Problems achieving glow around lights

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, lighting, compositing-nodes

Ok, new to using compositing nodes/tweaking the world color here but just watched some tutorials on low key lighting and looked at [How to create a glowing fog effect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82300/how-to-create-a-glowing-fog-effect) to mimic their fog glare node setup. I'm in cycles.

I'm having a tough time understanding, with background color negligible (I always render on transparent then put background in later), how to achieve this dusk type lighting with a central glowing node:

[image]

This is what I have with some volume scatter and just one, small light plane:

[image]

Even if I put a background color in the lighting is off. How can I achieve a more dramatic, dusk/motel light like lighting?

Comment: Note that if you use a transparent background you will not be able to see it in the compositor's viewer. Also note that if you save your image as PNG the glow will be missing. Read: [How do I get the Glare node to output transparent instead of Black background
](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824)

Comment: If you are using volume scatter, you might need to increase the intensity of the light source.

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/132506/1853

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You´re on the right track. After you do what you show on your picture, you need to go to the COMPOSITOR, and add a GLOW node, to help you boost the look you´re going for.
Also if you want "in scene" glows, you need to create a cube, set it to wireframe visual override, use the cube with a VOLUME material, set density to 0.02 and and there will be a soft "mist" on your scene which now the light can bounce and absorbe from the lights.
When you take your render into the compositor, you can adjust brightness and contrast to intensify the look of the lights. 
You can also set a general volume pass for the world.
Thank you if you vote my answer.
[image]

BFCT_Schiller