# Trying to add glow effect to runes

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I'm currently working on the "Sword in the stone" tutorial from [CGFastTrack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHv4VDoCwYc) but my computer can't support Blender 2.8. How can I make the runes glow in Blender 2.79?
[image: Text]

Comment: Cycles or Blender Internal? If Cycles, I believe the Glare Node/Fog Glow effect in Compositing will allow such effect. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/compositing/types/filter/glare.html

Comment: possible duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82300/how-to-create-a-glowing-fog-effect/82328#82328