# Emission 'Aura' Effect (2.79b Cycles)

Tags: node-editor, light

I have a scene set up with some objects with really nice shaders I mixed up in the Node Editor, and they look really good. However, I am trying to create a light blooming effect on the emission effect applied to one of my shaders. I have ramped up the strength of the emission effect, but while it makes it brighter, it doesn't give it the 'aura' look that I am seeking. Any advice on how to create the effect I am looking for?

Comment: Okay... sorry for my confusion, but as I just started using Blender, I am not familiar. So I need to go back to 2.8 and use something called the compositor to add a glare node?

Comment: @MikeGraves No, the compositor has been there for a while. There is no "glare" or "aura" effect by default in Cycles (although you could use volumetrics to achieve something similar). I don't know about Eevee, but it might have another feature. Bottom line, just follow the linked answer in any relatively recent version of Blender (not 2.8).

Comment: related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender/15704#15704 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54168/any-way-to-control-light-halos-in-the-compositor-based-on-emission-level/54173#54173 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31599/how-can-i-make-a-simple-volumetric-light-on-cycles/31613#31613

Comment: Sorry that was a confusing comment. JakeD is correct. Just follow the link that JtheNinja posted. I just mentioned in the new version of Blender coming out at the end of the year, will have and easier way to do this. Just fyi

Comment: I see! So the problem is that the effect I am looking for doesn't exist in the renderer I am using. Darn... all the rest of my effects were made using the Node Editor in Cycles; when I switch to Blender Render, literally everything in my scene vanishes (I habitually keep my view set to Render Mode right now, since I am still learning, and it helps me to see the effects of things as I am doing them). I suppose I should learn about volumetrics, then. Thanks a lot, everyone!

Comment: You're sort of correct. Maybe this will clear it up a little. You do NOT need to switch to Blender Render. Think of the compositor as a separate  program like Photoshop or After Effects. Once you are done with Cycles you switch to the Compositor and add any little tweaks likes streaks and blur and make some slight color adjustments. Maybe check out one of these videos https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=compositor+blender

Comment: Ah... so I need to learn about the compositor. I don't see it as an option anywhere in my interface, but I am sure that I will be able to get there using a video tutorial. Thanks again, that really helps!

Comment: Good luck, Blender is technically 4 programs in one, 3D program, Compositor (similar to after effects and photoshop), video editor (like premiere and final cut) and you can make video games (like unity and unreal (although they are taking this out at the end of the year)). So if you dont know the other programs like PS etc.. I would suggest learning the built in programs in Blender.

Comment: @icYou520 For correctness, Blender is sort of like multiple programs, but if you want to put it that way, it is way more than 4. For example, we have a camera/object tracker, a text editor, Python environment, and full-fledged animation tools as well.